# Openwrt library for REST both client and server

Tags: rest, post, client-server, openwrt

I'm developing an application on openwrt where I need to be able to send HTTP POST's and also receive them. This means I need to be both client and server simultaneously.

The ideia is to support the modes bellow in real time

-> poll mode - where send a POST to a server and process the answer

-> push mode - where I receive a POST from a client and have to send an answer

So far I only found libraries that implement the server or client side but never both. I could use two different libraries to achieve the result I want but it seems a bit "dirty". Here is what I found so far:

-> libcurl - Implements the client side

-> libmicrohttpd - Implements the server side

-> libwebsockets - Implements websockets but I'm not really sure is suited for what I want and needs some further testing

Someone knows a any better suited library? I'm kinda stuck at the moment :)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing any details of your application I suggest the following. Make a basic and simple solution using:

- **wget** for poll mode
- **uhttpd** for push mode

Write an ash script that glues these two building blocks together. Use cgi-bin to run the script in poll mode.